# how to parallelize nested do loops

Tags: parallelization

I have four Do loops which the outer loops iterate over the inner loops. This is my code

```
    jjp = 0;
    terms = 2;
    la = Table[0, {i, 1, 8}, {j, 1, 8}];
    SetSharedVariable[la, ii]
    Do[Do[m = -n + (jj - 1); jp = jjp + jj; iip = 0;
       Do[ParallelDo[u = -v + (ii - 1); ip = iip + ii;
         Print[jp, ip, KroneckerDelta[n, v] KroneckerDelta[m, u]]; 
         la[[jp, ip]] = KroneckerDelta[n, v] KroneckerDelta[m, u];, {ii,2v+1}];
         iip = ip;, {v, terms}];, {jj, 2 n + 1}]; 
      jjp = jp;, {n, terms}];
    la // MatrixForm
```

with above code I will got following result

```
    {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
```

But the result should be the following

```
    {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
     {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
```

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your question title doesn't match your question. Please consider re-titling. As for your actual question: without knowing what you're trying to do, we can't answer the question, because there is no context given for the correct result. Obviously we can't fix what you've done unless we know *why* the result should be the second list rather than the actual output from the code.

Comment: In this code I have KroneckerDelta[i,j] which should give zero unless i=j. Therefore we should have an Identity matrix as a result for two nested do loop iterative over i and j but the result I got is different from identity matrix.

Comment: So you're trying to make the identity matrix? Why not just do `IdentityMatrix[8]`? Or is this a simple example of what you're trying to do, and you're trying to figure out why the code above doesn't work so that you can apply to your more complex problem? A couple of things: (1) you don't need to nest `Do` loops: see the docs for `Do`; (2) if you tell us what you're actually trying to do, we might come up with a better way (usually, in *Mathematica*, you don't need loops); (3) there are lots of useful built-ins like `IdentityMatrix`: get cozy with docs and learn!

Comment: Replacing ParallelDo with Do will give the expected Identity Matrix. If my understanding of the question is correct, the question is why ParallelDo doesn't give the same result that Do does. My guess is that there could be some initialization/kernel communication mixup issues. Notice that adding the line ip=3; in the loop makes both Do and ParallelDo return the expected Identity Matrix. Do[Do[m = -n + (jj - 1); jp = jjp + jj; iip = 0; ip = 3;Not quite sure though.

Comment: @Lotus. Aha! Now that makes more sense. I could not figure out what the question was (clearly from my comments). OP: please consider re-writing the text a little to make it explicit that the code *works* if you use `Do` but *doesn't* if you use `ParallelDo`.

Comment: Try debugging with this `Print` variant: `Print[{m, n, u, v, ii, jj, iip, jjp, ip, jp, 
  KroneckerDelta[n, v] KroneckerDelta[m, u]}]`. What you should see is that the changes to `ii` need not be ordered (that's the point of parallelizing) and this creates behavior differences for values that depend on `ii`.

Comment: Actually, this a simple example of what I am trying to do, to figure out why the code above doesn't work so that I can apply to my more complex problem. It's not simply just about generating an identity matrix so 'IdentityMatrix' doesn't the case in my real problem.

Answer (score 2):

This variant seems to work.

```
jjp = 0;
terms = 2;
la = ConstantArray[0, {8, 8}];
Do[
  Do[
   m = -n + (jj - 1); jp = jjp + jj; iip = 0;
   Do[
    SetSharedVariable[la];
    ParallelDo[
     private`u = -v + (ii - 1); private`ip = iip + ii;
     Print[{m, n, private`u, v, ii, jj, iip, jjp, private`ip, jp, 
       KroneckerDelta[n, v] KroneckerDelta[m, private`u]}];
     la[[jp, private`ip]] = 
      KroneckerDelta[n, v] KroneckerDelta[m, private`u],
     {ii, 2 v + 1}, DistributedContexts -> "Global`"];
    iip = iip + 2 v + 1,
    {v, terms}]
   ,
   {jj, 2 n + 1}];
  jjp = jp,
  {n, terms}];
la
```

Salient differences:
(1) Put `u` and `ip` into non-distributed contexts so there isn't "cross-talk" between kernels about their values.
(2) I changed the `iip` update following the innermost loop to add `2v+1`. This has the effect of making it behave independently of ordering of the inner loop.

Comment: Thanks for try to improve the code. But if you change `terms = 2;
la = ConstantArray[0, {8, 8}];` with`terms = 10;
la = ConstantArray[0, {terms (terms + 2), terms (terms + 2)}];` to generate the bigger matrix I will get by `AbsoluteTiming` for above modified code `{40.88, Null}` while for my code posted above without `ParallelDo` I will get `{0.0738672, Null}`.

Comment: The slowness of `ParallelDo` vs `Do` in this example is not new. It was already manifest in your original code. You asked how to correct the parallelized code. Making it faster is a very different matter. For that you might try parallelizing the outermost loop instead of innermost. Less communication overhead that way.

Comment: Thanks. The idea for using `ParallelDo` was to make it as much as possible faster. But it seems I did it in wrong way because I am not so familiar with parallelization. This is my try but doesn't work `terms = 10;ParallelEvaluate[jjp = 0];
la = ConstantArray[0, {terms (terms + 2), terms (terms + 2)}];
SetSharedVariable[la];ParallelDo[Do[m=-n+(jj-1);jp=jjp+jj; iip = 0;
    Do[Do[private`u=-v+(ii-1);private`ip=iip+ii;la[[jp,private`ip]] = KroneckerDelta[n,v] KroneckerDelta[m,private`u],{ii,2v+1}];iip=iip+2 v+1,{v,terms}],{jj,2n+1}];jjp=jjp+2n+1,{n,terms},DistributedContexts->"Global`"];`

Comment: I hope someone can give better guidance on how to parallelize the outer loop to get both speed and correctness. I also lack the expertise; I had enough trouble working out the correctness issues with the previous version.